# How to set sysctl using kernel command line parameter?

Tags: linux, command-line, grub2, sysctl, kernel-parameters

Is it possible to set Linux kernel `sysctl` settings (those usually set in `/etc/sysctl.d`) using kernel command line (those visible in `/proc/cmdline`)?

(Using `grub` config file `/etc/default/grub` variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="..."`.)

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Quiet boot. Setting `kernel.printk=3 3 3 3` using kernel command line parameter to avoid having to set it in `initramfs` to avoid kernel information leaks. https://phabricator.whonix.org/T950

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to do this from the kernel command line.

Comment: @adrelanos I assume by information leaks you're talking about symbol addresses, in which case who are you trying to avoid giving the information to? Assuming you've restricted access to dmesg, there's no reason to stop it from being printed at very early boot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sysctl parameters can be set via the [kernel command-line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) starting with kernel version [5.8](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/diff/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt?id=v5.8-rc1&id2=v5.7), [thanks to Vlastimil Babka](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Sysctl-Set-From-Linux-Boot) from SUSE.

```
sysctl.*=       [KNL]
                Set a sysctl parameter, right before loading the init
                process, as if the value was written to the respective
                /proc/sys/... file. Both '.' and '/' are recognized as
                separators. Unrecognized parameters and invalid values
                are reported in the kernel log. Sysctls registered
                later by a loaded module cannot be set this way.
                Example: sysctl.vm.swappiness=40
```